# No admin privileges at all. Windows 8 64bit

Tags: windows-8, administrator

So there's this computer which has two accounts on it:

- A regular one (with password and I know the password)
- An administrator (without password).

You can't access or modify anything related to admin privileges in any of the accounts. You can't run Command Prompt elevated (which means no activating built-in administrator). Can't access any settings. When logged on to the admin, it says it's the Administrator, but when trying to reinstall (Windows 8 was already installed when bought the computer), restore, or refresh, it says there are no administrator accounts on the computer.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not a computer genius(obviously), but I can surely tell the situation is pretty bad.

Comment: see if You find anything useful here: http://superuser.com/questions/239130/how-to-get-back-to-work-with-a-windows-7-pc-that-has-no-admin-account

Comment: Can you login as the administrator account and create a **new** administrator account and use that account with any success?

Comment: What evidence exactly do you have that leads you to state when you login as Admin *it says it's the Administrator*?

Comment: I'm surprised the Administrator account has no password.  That alone can cause all sorts of issues.  Can you log on as Administrator and try set/change its password to something? Fingers crossed that does the trick.

Comment: Use the sticky keys replaced by command line trick to reset password? http://lifehacker.com/5612487/hack-the-sticky-keys-feature-to-reset-a-forgotten-windows-password ... Or use the elevated cmd prompt provided to create a new account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Comment: @Twisty I can login as the administrator, but I cannot create a new one. Can't even modify any of the accounts. When I go to Control Panel/User Accounts and Family Safety/User Accounts, it says there, under my profile picture, that the user is administrator. But I don't have any administrator privileges.

Comment: @misha256 I can log on as administrator, but I can't modify any accounts. It goes like this: 1) I go to Control Panel/User Accounts and Family Safety/User Accounts 2) I click any of the titles 3) Mouse changes its layout for a few seconds(as if it was opening it) 4) Mouse goes back to it's regular form and nothing happens

Comment: @WernerCD My administrator account doesn't have a password on it. And because I don't have any administrator privileges, I can't access the elevated cmd.

Comment: @DavidPostill Actually I didn't forget my Windows password, because my administrator account doesn't have one

Comment: @leAsome Understood, but the link provides ways to create a new admin account that may fix your problem. See this particular answer superuser.com/a/333063 for example.

Comment: @DavidPostill I see. Unfortunately I don't have a repair disc

Comment: @Twisty When I was at the User Accounts, I noticed it says there that the administrator account is password protected. It's weird, because, as I earlier said, I don't have a password on it

Comment: I found a Windows 7 disc, but my pc won't recognize it. It works on all the other computers, though

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to a system repair disc or the recovery options via Windows?

If so, you could try the following command in the recovery command prompt:

```
net localgroup Administrators [username] /add
```

Comment: No, I don't have a repair disc and I cannot access any of the recovery options, because my UAC is on maximum safety. And I cannot access UAC.

Comment: Hmm... Any recovery partition? A friend's/family member's disc you can borrow?

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned this in the comments and figured I'd explode this into a full answer: use the Sticky Keys "exploit" to get an elevated command prompt.

[Reset password with Sticky Keys -PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/249181/how_to_reset_your_windows_password.html)

> Reset Your Windows Password Using the Command Prompt
>
> 1. Boot your computer using your Windows installation disc.
> 2. Wait for the setup files to load, and select your language. Click Next.
> 3. Click the Repair your computer link on the Install Windows screen.
> 4. Select the operating system to repair, and note the drive letter on which the OS is installed (it is probably C: or D:). Click Next.
> 5. Click Command Prompt at the bottom of the list of recovery tools.
> 6. Backup sethc.exe. In the Command Prompt window, type
>      copy c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe c:\windows\system32\sethc.old
>      and press Enter.
> 7. Replace sethc.exe with cmd.exe. Type
>      copy /y c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe
>      and press Enter.
> 8. Exit the Command Prompt and reboot the computer.

At this point, you should be either at the logon screen, or on your desktop. Press shift five times. BAM! you should now have an ELEVATED console

[image]

Notice: sethc.exe in the image.

Now... you should have the control to do what you need. Add/change a password?

```
net user administrator Thup3rTh3cr3tP@sswordZOMGWTFBBQ!!!
```

[Disable UAC from the console](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-or-disable-uac-from-the-windows-vista-command-line/)?

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

With elevated command prompt, you should be able to do what you need - if not via CMD.EXE then you can most likely switch to Powershell and do it. With UAC disabled, you should be able to do whatever you need.